# Plot function on different intervals with different colors

Tags: plotting, color

[image: Sin[x]]

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
          PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-1, 1}}], 
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, π, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
          PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-1, 1}}]]
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this? Especially, one that does not require repeating the Plot command 2 times ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[x < Pi, Red, Blue]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-1, 1}}]
```

or

```
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
 Mesh -> {{Pi}},
 MeshShading -> {Red, Blue},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-1, 1}}]
```

or

```
 Plot[{ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], 0 <= x <= Pi],
 ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], Pi <= x <= 2 Pi]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Blue]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And if I want to make the blue region dashed? I tried MeshShading -> {Red, {Blue, Dashed}} without any luck..

Comment: you need to use `Directive`: `MeshShading->{Red,Directive[Blue,Dashed]}`

Answer (score 1):

Not a simpler way：

```
plt = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
{d, opt} = {Cases[plt, Line[x_] -> x, Infinity][[1]], plt[[2]]};
{r, b} = GatherBy[d, #[[1]] <= Pi &];
Graphics[{Thick, {Red, Line@r}, {Blue, Line@b}}, opt]
(*ListLinePlot[{r,b},PlotStyle->{{#,Red},{#,Blue}}&@Thick]*)
```

[image]