# Multiple curves plotted with different colours

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, color

I am trying to use `ColorFunction` for 2 functions on the same plot. I only want the cubic equation to change colour.

```
Plot[{-x^3 + 3.5*x + 0.5, y = 2.9*Tanh[5 x] + 0.3}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, 
      PlotRange -> {-3, 3.5}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> {{Darker[Green], Thick}, {Blue, Thick}}, 
      ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[x > 1, Red, Black]], 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

This is what the code above produces:

[image]

This is ideally how i would like it to be displayed. Is this possible in *Mathematica* without using the drawing tool?

[image]

Comment: You could use `Show[plot1, plot2]` where each plot has only one function with the corresponding options.

Comment: Related: [(1128)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1128/121), [(8199)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8199/121), [(16262)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16262/121), [(19004)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19004/121), [(22571)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22571/121), [(42235)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42235/121)

Answer (score 5):

[`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeshFunctions.html) is useful for discrete changes in color in [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html):

```
Show[
 Plot[2.9*Tanh[5 x] + 0.3, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3.5}, 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}],
 Plot[-x^3 + 3.5*x + 0.5, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, Mesh -> {{-1, 1}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Darker@Green, Black}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Change the numbers in `Mesh -> {{-1, 1}}` to move the transition points.  Change the colors in   `MeshShading -> {Darker@Green, Black}` to get a different arrangement of colors.

Answer (score 2):

As b.gatessucks writes in his comment, you want make two plots and combine them with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html). Also you need to modify your color function a little.

```
p1 = Plot[-x^3 + 3.5*x + 0.5, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, 
   PlotRange -> {-3, 3.5},
   Axes -> False,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> None,
   PlotStyle -> Thick,
   ColorFunction -> (If[Abs[#] > 1, RGBColor[0, .6667, 0], RGBColor[0, 0, 0]] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> None];
p2 = Plot[2.9*Tanh[5 x] + 0.3, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, 
   PlotRange -> {-3, 3.5},
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image: plot]